# Handlebars Partial is not working

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, partials

I'm trying to generate a nested `ul>li` list mark-up by [Handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars). So, I'm using partials in handlebars.

But, somehow the following code is not working. Can you please mention, what am doing wrong.

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars');

var source = '<ul>{{> list}}</ul>';
handlebars.registerPartial('list', 
                           '{{#children}}' +
                           '    <li>' +
                           '        {{name}}' +
                           '        {{#children}}' +
                           '        <ul>' +
                           '            {{> list}}' +
                           '        </ul>' +
                           '        {{/children}}' +
                           '    </li>' +
                           '{{/children}}');

var template = handlebars.compile(source);
var children = [
  {
    name: 'Abcd',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'dfrt',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'fgtd',
            children: [

            ]
          },
          {
            name: 'ghty',
            children: [

            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
var generatedString = template(children);
console.log(generatedString); // Only produces '<ul></ul>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike this [mustache example](https://gist.github.com/jrdmcgr/5816645) your example resembles of, you can just use the Handlebars `#each` helper

Source:

`var source = ' <ul>{{#each this}}{{> list this}} {{/each}}</ul>'`

The helper:

```
<li>
{{name}}
{{if children}}
  <ul>
  {{#each children}}
    {{> list this}}
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/if}}
</li>
```

Result:

- Abcd

  - dfrt

    - fgtd
    - ghty